# Configutration Profile "Not Verifed" in iOS v.8.3 and above

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, configuration-files

I want to sign a Configuration Profile for my app which I am downloading from server and then installing it on my device, this is working perfectly for iOS version 7.0, 7.1, ... , 8.2 and for installing profile it is showing "Verified" status. But for iOS v. 8.3 and above while installing the profile is showing status as "Not Verified". 
 I am using certificate from https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ for ROOT I am using certificate name [Apple Inc. Root Certificate](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/) and for Intermediate certificate I am using [Apple IST CA 2 - G1 Certficate](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/).
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.